# Improve dompdf rendering

Tags: php, pdf, dompdf

Here is the dompdf rendering of my SO profile page....

https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-I8istAg8Z6UmJDVHEtUkZOUDQ/edit

here's the code

```
<?php 

require_once("dompdf/dompdf_config.inc.php");
$html = file_get_contents('http://stackoverflow.com/users/1461078/samidh-t'); 
$base_path = 'http://'.$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] ;
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();

if ( isset($base_path) ) {
  $dompdf->set_base_path($base_path);
}

$dompdf->load_html($html);              
$dompdf->render();                     
$dompdf->stream('file.pdf' , array("Attachment" => 0));

?>
```

the rendering is not even close to the profile page.
What can be done to improve this rendering ?

Answer (score 1):

Dompdf - from memory, renders pages ok when the css and html are simple - lots of floats do not work - and you will find rendering web pages as pdf's using dompdf difficult enless you are writing the html and css yourself. (or parsing the input files first and modifying them).

What is your overall goal?

I have used dompdf to create pdf reports of data from a database and have had success but not using 'float' or any other advances css rules.

Dompdf info on css rules it can handle are here:

From this page:
https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf/blob/master/README.md

This text:

> Limitations (Known Issues) not particularly tolerant to poorly-formed HTML input (using 
>   Tidy first may help). large files or
>   large tables can take a while to render CSS float is not supported
>   (but is in the works). If you find this project useful, please
>   consider making a donation.